# How to read desired rows from large CSV files in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to search for data from a CSV file and pass on the data to another python code.
The CSV file has 100000+ rows and from them, I want to pass on the requested data per my choice.

**Actual Code:**

```
input_file = 'trusted.csv'
users = []
with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rows, None)
    for row in rows:
      user = {}
      user['username'] = row[0]
      user['id'] = int(row[1])
      user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
      user['name'] = row[3]
      users.append(user)
```

**Parsing data to code:**

```
g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
target_group.access_hash
```

The Actual code will parse **All** the rows from the CSV file and I am trying to find a solution for a python code that can pass on data - like from 11 to 20 rows, 50 to 100 rows likewise.

I tried the below code but received an error when the data was parsed to another python code:

```
import CSV


input_file = 'lucky280.csv'

start = 10
stop = start + 10
users = []
with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    for  i, line in enumerate(rows):
        if i >= start:
            users.append(line)
        if i > stop:
            break
            for row in rows:
              user = {}
              user['username'] = row[0]
              user['id'] = int(row[1])
              user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
              user['name'] = row[3]
              users.append(user)
```

ERROR : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 10, in 
    print ("Adding {}".format(user['id']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

If I use the Actual code the file reading will work fine but it will parse all the data in the file.

Please HELP!

After recommendation I also tried

```
input_file = 'lucky280.csv'
users = []
from itertools import islice
with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    rowiter = islice(rows, 3, 5)
    for item in rowiter:
            for row in rows:
              user = {}
              user['username'] = row[0]
              user['id'] = int(row[1])
              user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
              user['name'] = row[3]
              users.append(user)
```

got the below error

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-108-9f4099c2e53d> in <module>()
     10               user = {}
     11               user['username'] = row[0]
---> 12               user['id'] = int(row[1])
     13               user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
     14               user['name'] = row[3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `islice` from `itertools`

So here i have as sample csv file

```py
    X      Y
0  21  test3
1   8  test1
2  75  test1
3  26  test2
4  98  test3
5  63  test3
6  65  test3
7  39  test3
8  74  test1
9  26  test2
```

And suppose I want only rows 3 and 4

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
...     rows = csv.reader(f)
...     rowiter = islice(rows, 3, 5)
...     for item in rowiter:
...             print(item)
```

gives me the following output

```
['2', '75', 'test1']
['3', '26', 'test2']
```

**Update**

```
input_file = 'trusted.csv'
start = 10
stop = start + 10
users = []

with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")    
    rowiter = islice(rows, start, stop)
    for row in rowiter :
      user = {}
      user['username'] = row[0]
      user['id'] = int(row[1])
      user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
      user['name'] = row[3]
      users.append(user)
```

Comment: Update the code. P.S. I cannot test that code. I added that code to show how to modify your code so that it works. Hope that helps

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-108-9f4099c2e53d> in <module>()
     10               user = {}
     11               user['username'] = row[0]
---> 12               user['id'] = int(row[1])
     13               user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
     14               user['name'] = row[3]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: got the same error - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: the error corresponds to index out of range when you are assigning the row value to the `user` dictionary. Try debugging it by printing the row before you update the `user` dictionary